# Saving dictionary to file then loading file to edit dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

right now i can use my program to create and edit a dictionary but i need to be able to save the dictionary vaiable to a file and then load that file and replace the old dictionary.

something like this:

```
Dict1={key:value}
Dict2=Dict1
```

save Dict2 to file and then load file so i can replace Dict1

```
Dict1=Dict2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use json!
Json its fast and more secure than eval/pickle. (and btw produces smaller files than pickle)
Json won't execute any code (there is no "magic" involved).

```
import json

# Write to file
d={123:123}
json.dump(d,open("myfile","w"))


# Load from file
d = json.load(open("myfile","r")
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  It avoids the security risks of pickle and the serialization issues of repr() and eval()

Comment: In general cases it's good soultion, but some data structures inside dictionary can be not serializable.

Comment: To circumvent this you could [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) the json serializer.

Answer (score 2):

Use module [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" } 
pickle.dump( favorite_color, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

But notice, that unpickling data from unsecured source could lead to security issues

Comment: You didn't inquire about his use case or mention the potential security risks here

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is this:

```
f=open("myFile", "w")
f.write(dict2)
f.close()
```

Later:

```
f=open("myFile", "r")
dict2=eval(f.read())
f.close()
```

The trick is that the string representation (which will be written to the file) of a dict is something like `'{ "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }'`

The eval() function interprets this string after reading from file and so returns a dict object.

However: Be careful: Someone may replace the content of the file with python-code to format your hard disk. If you have such concerns about security, you better use something like pickle.

Comment: Even easier to hack than pickle and less sane.  What if your dict has a time tuple in it?  This will fail then.